# How to detect whether apt-get requires a reboot using Bash?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, restart

I am writing a bash script (for apt-get based OS's) that automates the installations process of various programs. In this process I run "apt-get -fy update" and "apt-get -fy upgrade" sometimes. In the process of upgrading, occasionally, a restart is required.

My question: is there a way of testing if the system is asking for a restart after running "apt-get -fy upgrade"? I am trying to write the script for it to run from beginning to end without human any intervention.

Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the file /var/run/reboot-required which does exactly what you want. So we will have this:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -fy upgrade && [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && shutdown -r now
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall whether `apt-get` actually gives you a predictably formatted message informing you whether a restart is necessary, but if it does you could just check the output, e.g.  something like `apt-get -fy update | grep -q 'fill in restart message pattern' && reboot`.

Another probably less reliable alternative is to use `checkrestart` from the `debian-goodies` package.

Comment: Checkrestart is in the Lucid repositories: apt-cache search checkrestart >> debian-goodies - Small toolbox-style utilities for Debian systems. Besides, I found something about here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/checkrestart.1.html

Comment: The right package is called "debian-goodies". After installed, you can type: checkrestart -v (for verbose).

Answer (score -1):

If you do a

```
apt-get -fy update && shutdown -r now
```

it will respect the order and will update until finish and finally restart your server.

Comment: This is interesting but I'd like to restart only if absolutely necessary.